# Get domain from URL

Tags: php, url

OK, before you say "oh, come on! this is easy", I must inform you that I've been testing many many different methods for that specific thing, for a long time, and I haven't found any that **really** works for **any url**, and **any domain**.

**Examples :**

- http://www.this-is-a-url.com = this-is-a-url.com
- www.this-is-another.url.com/some-folder = this-is-another-url.com
- subdomain.somesub.domain.com/index.php = domain.com
- diff.erentltd.in = erentltd.in
- www.andanotherone.org.uk = andanotherone.org.uk

So, any ideas? Do you know of any working function/script?

---

**To anyone interested :** Please have a look at ***@bystwn22***'s answer. It's one of the smoothest working solutions you could possibly find! :-)

Comment: will not work without a list of ALL valid CTlds ek. something.com.tk is valid but something.com.at would be invalid. as com.at is not a ctld but a normal domain.

Comment: @Rufinus I know how tricky the issue is... :S

Comment: is your second example correct?  I think it should be `www.this-is-another-url.com/some-folder = this-is-another-url.com`

Comment: Here two useful links: https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List and http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: I don't think it's possible to distinguish between `importantsubdomain.domain.com` and `unimportantsubdomain.domain.com` without knowing in advance which subdomains are important or not. It's easy to discount `www.`, but pretty much anything else could be important. You can't even rely on a list of valid TLDs and which ones commonly have third-level domains, because there are a number of very large changes coming up in the domain industry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay try this, i know the question is really tricky :\

```
<?php
  $urls = array(
    "http://www.this-is-a-url.com",
    "www.this-is-another-url.com/some-folder",
    "subdomain.somesub.domain.com/index.php",
    "diff.erentltd.in",
    "www.andanotherone.org.uk"
  );

  foreach( $urls as $url ) {
    var_dump( get_domain( $url ) );
  }

  /** Output **/
  // string(17) "this-is-a-url.com"
  // string(23) "this-is-another-url.com"
  // string(10) "domain.com"
  // string(11) "erentltd.in"
  // string(20) "andanotherone.org.uk"
?>
```

Function `get_domain`

```
<?php
  function get_domain( $url ) {
    $regex  = "/^((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+)([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?$/i";
    if ( !preg_match( $regex, $url, $matches ) ) {
      return false;
    }
    $url    = $matches[3];
    $tlds   = array( 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'aero', 'af', 'ag', 'ai', 'al', 'am', 'an', 'ao', 'aq', 'ar', 'arpa', 'as', 'asia', 'at', 'au', 'aw', 'ax', 'az', 'ba', 'bb', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'bg', 'bh', 'bi', 'biz', 'bj', 'bm', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'bt', 'bv', 'bw', 'by', 'bz', 'ca', 'cat', 'cc', 'cd', 'cf', 'cg', 'ch', 'ci', 'ck', 'cl', 'cm', 'cn', 'co', 'com', 'coop', 'cr', 'cu', 'cv', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz', 'de', 'dj', 'dk', 'dm', 'do', 'dz', 'ec', 'edu', 'ee', 'eg', 'er', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fi', 'fj', 'fk', 'fm', 'fo', 'fr', 'ga', 'gb', 'gd', 'ge', 'gf', 'gg', 'gh', 'gi', 'gl', 'gm', 'gn', 'gov', 'gp', 'gq', 'gr', 'gs', 'gt', 'gu', 'gw', 'gy', 'hk', 'hm', 'hn', 'hr', 'ht', 'hu', 'id', 'ie', 'il', 'im', 'in', 'info', 'int', 'io', 'iq', 'ir', 'is', 'it', 'je', 'jm', 'jo', 'jobs', 'jp', 'ke', 'kg', 'kh', 'ki', 'km', 'kn', 'kp', 'kr', 'kw', 'ky', 'kz', 'la', 'lb', 'lc', 'li', 'lk', 'lr', 'ls', 'lt', 'lu', 'lv', 'ly', 'ma', 'mc', 'md', 'me', 'mg', 'mh', 'mil', 'mk', 'ml', 'mm', 'mn', 'mo', 'mobi', 'mp', 'mq', 'mr', 'ms', 'mt', 'mu', 'museum', 'mv', 'mw', 'mx', 'my', 'mz', 'na', 'name', 'nc', 'ne', 'net', 'nf', 'ng', 'ni', 'nl', 'no', 'np', 'nr', 'nu', 'nz', 'om', 'org', 'pa', 'pe', 'pf', 'pg', 'ph', 'pk', 'pl', 'pm', 'pn', 'pr', 'pro', 'ps', 'pt', 'pw', 'py', 'qa', 're', 'ro', 'rs', 'ru', 'rw', 'sa', 'sb', 'sc', 'sd', 'se', 'sg', 'sh', 'si', 'sj', 'sk', 'sl', 'sm', 'sn', 'so', 'sr', 'st', 'su', 'sv', 'sy', 'sz', 'tc', 'td', 'tel', 'tf', 'tg', 'th', 'tj', 'tk', 'tl', 'tm', 'tn', 'to', 'tp', 'tr', 'travel', 'tt', 'tv', 'tw', 'tz', 'ua', 'ug', 'uk', 'us', 'uy', 'uz', 'va', 'vc', 've', 'vg', 'vi', 'vn', 'vu', 'wf', 'ws', 'ye', 'yt', 'yu', 'za', 'zm', 'zw' );
    $parts  = array_reverse( explode( ".", $url ) );
    $domain = array();

    foreach( $parts as $part ) {
      $domain[] = $part;
      if ( !in_array( strtolower( $part ), $tlds ) ) {
        return implode( ".", array_reverse( $domain ) );
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Here two useful links: https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List and http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: Thank you, i think all tlds from `data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt` is already on my list :)

Comment: Buddy, I *think* you nailed it. (and I'm saying "think" because I still cannot believe it's working... lol - even though I've *thoroughly* tested it). Great job! Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a simpler solution. Due to the issues we faced with `parse_url`

```
check("www.google.com");

function check($url) {
        if (!preg_match("/^http/", $url)) $url = "http://" . $url;
        echo preg_replace("/.*\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)/", "$1", parse_url ( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this outputs: `this-is-a-url.com`,`url.com`,`domain.com`,`erentltd.in`,`org.uk`.

Comment: yes i know it doesn't handle the UK one, neither does yours because your logic there is really hardcoded. we need to work against a valid tld dictionary for it to really work

Comment: @AmalMurali nope. what he ment is you check for .uk, but there are more second level domains besides .uk

Answer (score 1):

Well you actually need 2 lists: second level domains and top level domains.

1. Get host from your url with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), lets say it will be *subdomain.domain.org.uk*
2. Explode it by dot and take last two elements of that array, concatenated by dot again (*org.uk*). If thats one of second-level domains - add previous element of array, and you have your domain (*domain.org.uk*).
3. Otherwise your domain is what you've checked in the step 2 (if last element of array is one of top level domains, you can skip this check if you are pretty sure the domain is valid). If your original host was *subdomain.domain.com*, then you have checked that *domain.com* is **not** a second-level domain, that means *domain.com* is what you were looking for.

Here is the [list of second-level domains](https://github.com/gavingmiller/second-level-domains). Or you can try to find a better one.

Comment: I've took a look on the list, and you actually need to concatenate 3 last elements (if it was exploded to 3 or more elements) and do the same check as with last 2 elements, since second level domains could be like "ecape.school.za". Tho, it doesn't change the algorithm much.